# How to the add elements in two arrays, but in reverse order?

Tags: c++, arrays, nested-loops, decrement

The purpose of this code is to add the elements in the two arrays, but in reverse order. **I  don't understand what I did wrong for this not to Compile**(Syntax,Loop, or Array Error??). Could you point me in the right direction? Thank you!!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ARRAY1_LEN = 3;
    const int ARRAY2_LEN = 2;

    int MyInts1[ARRAY1_LEN] = { 35, -3, 0};
    int MyInts2[ARRAY2_LEN] = {20, -1};

    cout << "Multiplying each int in MyInt1 by each in MyInts2 ... But Backwards:" << endl;

    for(int Array1Index = 0; Array1Index < ARRAY1_LEN - 1; Array1Index--);
        for(int Array2Index = 0; Array2Index < ARRAY2_LEN -1; Array2Index--);
        cout << MyInts1[Array1Index] << " x " << MyInts2[ Array2Index ] << " = " << MyInts1[Array1Index] * MyInts2[Array2Index] << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're starting at index 0 and going backwards forever. It looks like you thought changing a `++` to a `--` is all you had to do.

Comment: And doing nothing in the `for` body...

Comment: Your code should not compile - please post your actual code

Comment: @JosephMansfield   So what value would I have to set Array1Index and Array2Index?

Comment: @MikeMB That's the thing it doesn't compile and I don't understand why.

Comment: @Ham You need `Array1Index` to start at the end of the array, and make sure it is always greater than or equal to 0. And to expand on Diego's point - you should not put a `;` after a `for` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is not correct. You are starting at index `0` and then going backward. It means, that you are entering negative range (-1, -2, -3, ...) and every negative number satisfies loop condition.

It rather should be:

```
int main()
{
    const int ARRAY1_LEN = 3;
    const int ARRAY2_LEN = 2;

    int MyInts1[ARRAY1_LEN] = { 35, -3, 0 };
    int MyInts2[ARRAY2_LEN] = { 20, -1 };

    cout << "Multiplying each int in MyInt1 by each in MyInts2 ... But Backwards:" << endl;

    int start_1 = ARRAY1_LEN > 0 ? ARRAY1_LEN - 1 : 0;
    int start_2 = ARRAY2_LEN > 0 ? ARRAY2_LEN - 1 : 0;

    for(int Array1Index = start_1; Array1Index >= 0; Array1Index--)
    {
        for(int Array2Index = start_2; Array2Index >= 0; Array2Index--)
        {
            cout << MyInts1[Array1Index] << " x " << MyInts2[ Array2Index ] << " = " << MyInts1[Array1Index] * MyInts2[Array2Index] << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code will also work properly if at least one of the arrays will be empty.

Oh, and one more thing: your code was also totally wrong, because you had semicolons (`;`) after `for`, which means, that every loop had an empty body. So, even if your `for`s were correct, you wouldn't see anything anyway.

Comment: There's a few issues with this answer. Firstly, you are computing `start_2` from `ARRAY1_LEN`. Secondly, the computation of `start_1` and `start_2` is unnecessary because an array must always have length greater than 0. And thirdly, the `for` loop condition should be `>=`, otherwise the first element will not be used.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Yes, I noticed that, thank you. Copy-paste could be tricky when it comes to the code :) Already fixed. Also, computation of `start_1` and `start_2` is useful and better than putting something like `ARRAY1_LEN - 1` inside `for`. It is also handy for the debugging process.

Comment: There is no reason to introduce that extra logic. The compiler will produce an error if Actually, if `ARRAY1_LEN` is zero or less (for whatever reason), So as long as the program compiles at all, `int start_1 = ARRAY1_LEN > 0 ? ARRAY1_LEN - 1 : 0;` will always evaluate to `int start_1 =ARRAY1_LEN-1`. And even if the compiler would not produce an error, the effect of a zero or negative array length would be that the loop body would never be executed. So, if you really think, you have to introduce an alias for the last valid index, you should probably at least omit the  ternary statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your program:

1. The whole loop body consits only of the semicolons after the for loop instead of the code you actually want to run inside the loops. This also explains, why your code doesn't compile: your multiplication is not part of the loop bodies and as a result `Array1Index` and `Array2Index` - which are defined in the loop headers - do no longer exist.
2. Although you are decreasing the arry indices, you still start at 0, so you would access negative array indices.

So your code should actually look like this:

```
for (int Array1Index = ARRAY1_LEN - 1 ; Array1Index >= 0; Array1Index--){
    for (int Array2Index = ARRAY2_LEN - 1; Array2Index >=0; Array2Index--){
        cout << MyInts1[Array1Index] << " x " << MyInts2[Array2Index] << " = " << MyInts1[Array1Index] * MyInts2[Array2Index] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is one error in your code: you are accessing `MyInts1[ARRAY1_LEN]`, which is an error. Such element does not exist.